# Vertx web Routing

Tags: ruby, vert.x

I'm new to vertx-web. I'm building web application using ruby vertx-web. I would like to serve static file (index.html) . and  My index.html packed inside webroot folder.
My index.html file will load for http://localhost:8088. I need to serve index.html for localhost:8088/demo OR localhost:8088/test OR http://localhost:8088/* (* could be anything and it should serve index.html).

directory structure:

- frontend

  - webroot

    - index.html
    - index.css
  - sever.rb

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
router.route("/static/*").handler(&VertxWeb::StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("webroot").method(:handle))
```

Comment: Hi niraj, router.route_with_regex(".*/index.html").handler() { |ctx|
  response = ctx.response()
  response.put_header("content-type", "text/html")
  response.set_chunked(true)
  response.send_file("webroot/index.html")
}   and it loads index.html but it will not load css and js files those inside index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could define a default route as last route and set a handler which only sends the index.html file:

```
router.route().handler(rc -> {
  rc.response().sendFile("webroot/index.html");
});
```

This is the Java version but translating it to Ruby should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

following code works for me.

```
router.route_with_regex(".*/index.html").handler() { |routingContext|  router.route().handler(&VertxWeb::StaticHandler.create().method(:handle))

   response = routingContext.response()

   response.put_header("content-type", "text/html") 
   response.set_chunked(true) 

   response.send_file("webroot/index.html")

}
```